# How I can create folders in hierarchical orders using Google Drive V3 APIs

Tags: angular, google-drive-api, service-accounts, create-directory

I need to create a folder inside a folder in google drive using google drive api v3 in angular.

I need to create folder in the admin's google drive account not in the client's google drive.

Explaining by a example:

Loggined User 1 Id: ABC123
Date : 17-07-2023

So I want to create a folder ABC123 , then in that i want to create a folder 17-02-2023.

folder 1 -> ABC123
-> folder 2 ->17-02-2023

But, the condition is I want to create the folder in admins google drive not in the clients.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.